# How can I determine if a process is running unseen in terminal?

Tags: terminal, process

For ex - if I enter ping one.com the process will keep running - if I want to stop that process, I can type Ctrl C which if I'm not mistaken, will kill the process completely. If instead, I stop it with Ctrl Z, isn't it true that the process can still be operating in the background at some level? How is one able to spot a condition where a process is running but can't be seen on the terminal screen? Thanks.

Comment: "I stop it with Ctrl Z, isn't it true that the process can still be operating in the background" — Not usually, no. The process can intercept the signal and perform shenanigans to make itself continue to run, but in general and by default, suspended means suspended, and after Ctrl-Z the process is suspended and *not* running.

Comment: Run the `jobs` command to see what jobs are in background or suspended

Comment: Yes - this seems to be the place to start, will remember - thanks .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `jobs` built-in to see running tasks for your current shell.

```
$ ping google.com >/dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 32406

$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 ping google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 &

$ ping google.com
[...]
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ping google.com

$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 ping google.com > /dev/null 2>&1 &
[2]+  Stopped                 ping google.com
```

To kill all running jobs, you can leverage `jobs -p` which lists the pids of all jobs.

```
$ for job in $(jobs -p); do kill $job; wait $job; done
```

Further reading: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html

Comment: In the referenced TLDP.com page, especially see "fg" and "bg".

Comment: Very helpful - this is what I was looking for - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

run `ps -aux | grep "processname"` to see if process running

run `kill "processID"` to kill specified process, PID is second set of numbers in previous command in line with target process

run `killall "processname"` to kill all processes with defined name

Comment: You can usually also `pgrep "process name"` to get a list of PIDs matching that name

Comment: This is very helpful - I can now spot the ID of the processes and am tuned in to that. Thanks.